# Limits of the Waterfall function ... or not?

Tags: matlab, axis, figure, waterfall

I have a problem to figure out how in a waterfall figure the x axis can correspond to the x values, and not their point number. This question seems rather simple but in my particular case (due to the size of vectors) it's not easy to get the correct figure. So i really need your help ... after several hours of unsatisfied results.

Assuming that two vectors x and y of the same length are recorded at a time t. This procedure is performed k times. I finally want to plot with waterfall y versus x for the different times.
I give you a script that corresponds to the experiment where xx is just added to get here two continuous functions x and y for the different times. The result is almost perfect but I would like the x-y values on the corresponding x, y axis instead of the point number.

```
xx=0:0.1:8;
for t=1:2:11
   x(t,:)=sin(t*xx.^2);
   y(t,:)=cos(t*xx.*4);
end
waterfall(x,y)
```

The problem comes probably from the different size of x, y with t. Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Thank's Cris, you're right. May be my example in the script is not the good one. I would like to know how to plot y vs x for the different times but i have a problem related to their size to construct a new matrix Z for waterfall(Z). For my example we can assume another x function which would be monotonously increasing but with different values for each time.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer as valid if it helped you. Also, do not repeat questions, ask only once each problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments:

1. `waterfall` takes either `Z` or `X,Y,Z` as coordinates. So it takes your `x` matrix as `Z`, and the other argument is mapped to the `C` input, which dictates color. You can see that the plot is the same if you do `waterfall(x)`, except with different colors.
2. Your `x` is not monotonically increasing, so if you plot `x(t,:)` vs `y(t,:)` for any `t`, you'll get a web-like graph, not anything nice to look at.

So I'll plot `xx` vs `y`, and I'm modifying your `y` a bit so it looks nicer. I hope you can take this idea and modify it to do what you need.

The code below doesn't use `waterfall` at all, it simply calls `plot3` once for each `t`. It might be possible to call `plot3` with your full `x` and `y` matrices, but this is just as easy.

In the `plot3` call, the x-coordinates are given by `xx`, the y-coordinates by `t` (simply repeated to match the expected size), and the z-coordinates by `y`:

```
xx = 0:0.1:8;
for t = 1:2:11
   y = cos(t*xx/4);
   plot3(xx,repmat(t,size(xx)),y)
   hold on
end
xlabel('x')
ylabel('t')
zlabel('y=cos(tx/4)')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Cris for your advice. I will try to use plot3 but as x,y,t had not the same length I have preferred wto use waterfall without any success

Comment: It's perfect with plot3, I just had a patch to control the color with the y values. Thanks a lot Cris